# Calculate Overdue Sales which uses the condition

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to calculate in Power BI using dax overdue sales < current month.

Comment: That's great - good luck!

Comment: Seriously though, that's not a question. Please describe your problem, show your research and what have you tried so far. And welcome to stackoverflow ;).

Comment: CALCULATE(
    SUM(Backlog[Extended_Resale_USD]),
    FILTER(Backlog,MONTH(Backlog[CRD]) = MONTH(TODAY())),
    FILTER(Backlog,YEAR(Backlog[CRD]) = YEAR(TODAY()))
    )

Comment: Salesdue = CALCULATE(SUM(sales[sale_USD]),sales[RequestDate]<TODAY(),
not ISBLANK(sales[RequestDate])
)----but instead of today i want to use current month . i am not sure how tsolve this so that it can provide me outstanding sales from current years till the start of the year eg 2010

Comment: In Power BI almost everything is context dependent. Please put in some effort and try to present your question in a structured **and concise** way - what is the relevant underlying data (a representative sample), what is your desired result in a visual, etc. Otherwise, there is no way for anyone to answer your question.